# upload and update android app in play store

Tags: android

I would like to upload my app in play store, when the new version of this app is available, I want to inform client about that new available version. Actually, I have no any experience with play store and I have no idea of how to handle the problem I have mention above. I would like someone to give me tutorial link or guide me what I do need to know.

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is for Programming related Questions. Please refrain posting such question here.

Comment: Once you build an apk, it will generate a keystore file(have it) then if there is version update use that keystore file and upload the latest apk file. It will automatically update the user once done.

Answer (score 1):

You not need to explicitly need to know clients that your application is updated. Just upload another apk with updated version code, it will automatically updates users that version is updated , so they can take update directly.